# jQuery json_encode

Tags: php, jquery, json

I've looked around for a Javascript/jQuery function which emulates PHP's `json_encode`, but all the ones I find (listed bellow) don't work.

1. http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/
2. http://phpjs.org/functions/json_encode:457

To check if it wasn't my array wasn't faulty I used phpjs `var_dump` with expected results.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What do you mean by _doesn't work_?

Comment: Returns an empty result, i.e. `[[]]`.

Comment: Well the [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) works. I have used it successfully before! Could you add the array or object you are trying to encode?

Comment: I added some extra detail. :3

Comment: So... why is json2.js no good for this?

Comment: Does it work in this context? I've just tried using json2.js and it returns the same result, "`[[]]`".

Comment: Then the problem is the JSON.

Comment: How can the problem be the JSON if the json has been encoded? Do you mean there is an error in the array and therefore it is a problem in the function `$.en.encode_data`?

Comment: Have you actually *looked* at the JSON yet?

Comment: _looked_? Like through console.log?

Comment: Like in opening it in a text editor or using your browsers "View Source" command.

Comment: I am using `$.ajax()` to call up the data, it wouldn't appear in the source code. I just went to double checked with `console.log()` and everything is there as expected. I've also used Google Chromes Developer Tool to check, and it still says `[[]]`. I've written in my question that even when using such function, like `var_dump` it shows, however when converting to json, it fails. 

Any alternative methods/ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot do this:

```
ret[$(this).attr("id")] = _recursiveItems(this);
```

because `var ret = []` declares `ret` as an [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and not an Object and `$(this).attr("id")` is non-numeric (its value is `head_1`). It is attempting to create an associative array which is [not supported.](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays#quickIDX9). JavaScript associative arrays are are meant to be numeric and even [considered harmful](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

If you change the declaration to `var ret = {}` then you can use [jquery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) to convert the object to JSON. Here is a [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TtvBm/1/) using the code in the question.